# Alexa App stops listening after first intent is triggered

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa App that has multiple `intents`, however, after any of the intents are triggered, Alexa shuts down. Each `intent` has `shouldEndSession` equal to `false`. Each of the intents has a callback:

```
callback(sessionAttributes,
     buildSpeechletResponse(speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
```

I've also logged the app, and `shouldEndSession` is equal to false. Does Alexa only listen for one intent?

Comment: Is buildSpeechletResponse() correctly setting shouldEndSession on the response? Can you edit your question to include that function?

Comment: Also, check out the alexa-sdk for nodejs. You can simply emit an `:ask` action in alexa-sdk to wait for a response, instead of having to build all of these responses on your own. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Comment: @anthonyneace I started logging everything and found that in my intent handlers when  `buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession)` is  executed `shouldEndSession` is undefined even though I have it set to `false`. By being `undefined` which even though would seem `falsy` was triggering `sessionEnded`. So now trying to determine how to get out of the skill gracefully.